# How can I stop Vetur to convert colSpan and rowSpan tags?

Tags: html, visual-studio, vue.js, nativescript, vetur

I am currently using nativescript-vue , I need **colSpan** and **rowSpan** tags to stay as the way it is.

`rowSpan="2"`  is turned into `rowspan="2"` by Vetur code formater.

### How to disable small case conversion features of Vetur?

Prettier does not correct cases but Vetur does.

Comment: It's a much better idea to change them all to lowercase than to make Vetur not change them. Even though there isn't yet a standard for this (or, if there is, I don't know about it) and, in theory, a web page with tags and attributes in all caps does work, the industry tends to always use lowercase for both tags and attributes, with or without dashes. This *"non-standard"* is also respected and supported by Vue, which you use. A `:is-open` attribute becomes `isOpen` prop. Also, any `<RandomComponent />` you write in your template actually becomes `<random-component></random-component>` in html.

Comment: Unfortunately changing all to lowercase is not an option since it's nativescript-vue code. **colSpan** is the only version nativescript can understand.

Comment: You seem to be right about that. I'm not experienced in writing NativeScript nor do I use VSCode. Also note my previous comment only stands true for web facing apps, not for NativeScript. However, in my estimation, you can't be the first one having this issue. And you've done no research whatsoever (at least as far as we can make from your question). I did a simple "Vetur NativeScript" google search and [here's what came up](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/issues/1332).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As outlined [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/issues/1332), you should change Vetur's default HTML formatter from `prettyhtml` to `prettier`.